# Write a JS function to find the first prime pair with a given step value

Tags: javascript

** Here is the question from Codewars.

The prime numbers are not regularly spaced. For example from 2 to 3 the step is 1. From 3 to 5 the step is 2. From 7 to 11 it is 4. Between 2 and 50 we have the following pairs of 2-steps primes:

3, 5 - 5, 7, - 11, 13, - 17, 19, - 29, 31, - 41, 43

We will write a function step with parameters:

g (integer >= 2) which indicates the step we are looking for,

m (integer >= 2) which gives the start of the search (m inclusive),

n (integer >= m) which gives the end of the search (n inclusive)

In the example above step(2, 2, 50) will return [3, 5] which is the first pair between 2 and 50 with a 2-steps.

So this function should return the first pair of the two prime numbers spaced with a step of g between the limits m, n if these g-steps prime numbers exist otherwise nil or null or None or Nothing (depending on the language).

Examples:

step(2, 5, 7) --> [5, 7] or (5, 7) or {5, 7}

step(2, 5, 5) --> nil or null

step(4, 130, 200) --> [163, 167] or (163, 167) or {163, 167}

Here is my solution- it is taking too long to pass the tests- how can I make it more efficient?

```
    function step(g, m, n) {
  var arr = [];
  function isPrime(num){
    for (var k=2; k<num; k++){
      if(num%k ===0){
        return false;
      }
   }return true;
  }
  for (var i= m; i < n; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)=== true){
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  var endArr=[];
  for(var l=0;l<arr.length;l++)
  for(var p=1;p<arr.length;p++){
    if(arr[l]-arr[l-p]=== g){
      endArr.push(arr[l])
      endArr.push(arr[l]-g)
    }
  }
  return endArr.slice(0,2).sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b;
})

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `isPrime` function is naive. You are testing every number from 2 to k. First, the only even prime is 2 so testing 4, 6, 8, etc is not necessary. You don't have to test every number up to `num`. Instead you can stop after `sqrt(num)`. Then it has been shown that all primes greater than 2 are of the form `6n-1 or 6n+1`. I.e. `6*1 - 1 = 5`, `6*1 + 1 = 7`, `6*2 - 1 = 11`, `6*2 + 1 = 13`, etc. (Not all are prime but numbers not of this form are not prime). Since the numbers you are looking at are rather small you could use a precalculated table of all primes. With something like Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points of interest here.

First, your implementation of `isPrime` is inefficient. The fastest way would be using the precached set (it's easy to prepare one), but even without it you should only check a candidate by dividing it by primes, dropping out when the next prime divisor becomes greater than `sqrt(cand)`.

For example, if you already know that 2, 3, 5, and 7 are primes, you can detect that `11` is a prime by dividing it only by 3 (as `5 > Math.sqrt(11)`) Oh, and did I mention that you'd never check even numbers greater than 2?

Second, your implementation attempts to find *all* the primes in the given range, and after that tries to find all the primes that satisfy the "difference condition". But remember, your task actually is finding the first pair of the two prime numbers with the given step.

With that in mind, why don't you just check a number (`n`), and if it's a prime, attempt to check `n + g`'s primeness? You can cache the result of that check, so that you skip it afterwards.

---

Here's one possible approach:

```
function findPrimesByStep(g, m, n) {
  let primes = new Set([2]);

  function isPrimeNumber(candidate) {
    if (primes.has(candidate)) {
      return true;
    }

    let lim = Math.sqrt(candidate);
    for (let prime of primes) {
      if (prime > lim) {
        break;
      }

      if (candidate % prime === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    primes.add(candidate);
    return true;
  }

  n = n - g;
  for (let i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
    let isPrime = isPrimeNumber(i);
    if (isPrime && i >= m && isPrimeNumber(i + g)) {
     return [i, i + g];
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

This is both incomplete and unoptimized (it doesn't check against trivial cases, it skips 2, one doesn't need primes greater than `sqrt(n)`), but shows how it can be done.